# change profile picture when click in link to the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have an user profile (/someuser) that I open using :

```
<Route path="/:user" component={Profile} />
```

The profile is like this:

```
export default function App(props) {

const [nick, setNick] = useState(props.match.params.user); //get the nick using props.
const [profile, setProfile_picture] = useState(profile_picture); // default one

useEffect(() => {

// get current user profile picture:
firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild('user').equalTo(props.match.params.user).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()){
            var img = snapshot.val().img;
            setProfile_picture(img);
        }
});
}, []);

return(
    <>
<img className={classes.profile} src={profile} />
<h1>{nick}</h1>
<Link to="/user2">Go to profile 2</Link>
</>
);
}
);
```

Supose I'm in /user profile and I click in the Link at the end of the code to go to the /user2. What I'd like to do is change the profile picture and the nick (without reload). Force after  click to update this informations... Any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger the `useEffect` based on params change because when the params change component is re-rendered by react-router and hence the state will not be re-initialized.

Triggering the useEffect on params change will ensure data is updated when params change.

Also make sure to `set nick` state too ni useEffect as that too needs to update on params change

```
useEffect(() => {

    // set nick state
    setNick(props.match.params.user);
    // get current user profile picture:
    firebase.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild('user').equalTo(props.match.params.user).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                var img = snapshot.val().img;
                setProfile_picture(img);
            }
    });
}, [props.match.params.user]);
```

Comment: Oh, I was near! Thanks a lot for your answer, friend!

Comment: Glad to have helped Rick

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean without reloading the page?  If so then I think you can make a boolean that toggles when you go to a different route and initiates then useEffect hook by putting it in the dependency array.  Or you could move the code to a separate component and pass it in as a prop.  Now to do it completely without redirecting the browser would be to use the toggle boolean as mentioned before, but using fetch api, axios, etc to send that nick to a backend and change it accordingly which I think is similar to an Ajax request I hope this helps.